# Stored procedure returns -1 after creating user

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have trouble with creating user. When I'm creating a new user my proc returns -1, but it must return users id.

Stored procedure running well and it is inserting data into the table, but returns -1

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateUser]
    @Address nvarchar(300),
    @BirthDay date,
    @Email nvarchar(64),
    @FullName nvarchar(300),
    @Image nvarchar(2000),
    @Password nvarchar(512),
    @PhoneNumber nvarchar(10),
    @Sex nvarchar(3),
    @RoleId int
AS
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] ([Address], [BirthDay], [Email], [FullName], [Image], [Password], [PhoneNumber], [Sex], [RoleId])
    VALUES (@Address, @BirthDay, @Email, @FullName, @Image, @Password, @PhoneNumber, @Sex, @RoleId)
    RETURN 0    
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RETURN -1
END CATCH
```

I have in my repository method Create:

```
public async Task<int> Create(User user)
{
    string sql = $"sp_CreateUser @BirthDay = '{user.BirthDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}', @Email = '{user.Email}', @FullName = '{user.FullName}', @Password = '{user.Password}', @RoleId = {user.RoleId}, @Address = '{user.Address}', @Image = '{user.Image}', @PhoneNumber = '{user.PhoneNumber}', @Sex = '{user.Sex}'";
    int result = await _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: your sql statement is either returning 0 (if valid) or -1 (if invalid).  This has little to nothing to do with C#.  You need to fix your SQL statement

Comment: If you want to return a value like this (just added User ID), the only reliable way is the Output Syntax (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql). Any other approach is prone to issues or race conditions. And as oppassum said, this is a SQL Question first, not a C# question.

Comment: Thx, I will try your suggestion, maybe they will help me)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your executesqlcommand line and run your sql profiler in management studio.  I suspect your single quotes are being duplicated and your parameter values in the actual sql statement look like ''2018-01-29'' with 2 single quotes.  Also check the length of all of your values you are passing.  If they exceed your defined limits it will error on the query and return -1.

Comment: Stored procedure running well, and it insert data into table but returns -1

Comment: It looks as though you need an out param, this will capture what is in the Return line in your stored procedure.  Check out this example, accepted answer is at the very bottom of the page:  https://forums.asp.net/t/2022266.aspx?how+can+i+use+asyn+await+to+execute+stroe+procedure

Comment: You need to use the `@Return_Value` output sql parameter, which I don't know how you do with EF. With "normal" `SqlCommand` the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` itself is the number of rows effected, *except* when `Set NoCount On` in which case `-1` is returned by the `SqlCommand`. I'd imagine this is the exact scenario with EF since the underlying SQL providers are the same. If I were to run this without EF and using ExecuteNonQuery, I'd except the result to be -1 so I don't think it's technically *wrong*...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF6 - ExecuteSqlCommandAsync - Get return parameter (declare scalar variable error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823148/ef6-executesqlcommandasync-get-return-parameter-declare-scalar-variable-err)

Comment: The dupe I linked above actually is for EF6. I just realized he was using output parameters and not return values. So what you should do instead is manually pass a `SqlParameter` with `Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` and `Name="@Return_Value"` and then inspect the value afterwards. But you'd have to update your procedure to return the new ID instead of `return 0` by using output clause or scope identity

Comment: And again it's not the *procedure* returning -1 because it hits the catch clause. It's the return value of the *method call* telling you the number of rows affected which is -1 because of `set NoCount on`. If you `set NoCount off`, you'll get a *method* return value of +1

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

I`ve added return parameter using SqlParameter and now everything working well.

```
public async Task<int> Create(User user)
        {
            var param = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@CreatedId",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };

            string sql = $"exec @CreatedId = sp_CreateUser @BirthDay = '{user.BirthDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}', @Email = '{user.Email}', @FullName = '{user.FullName}', @Password = '{user.Password}', @RoleId = {user.RoleId}, @Address = '{user.Address}', @Image = '{user.Image}', @PhoneNumber = '{user.PhoneNumber}', @Sex = '{user.Sex}'";
            int result = await _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, param);
            return (int)param.Value;
        }
```

Or another way is to set in Stored Procedure

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Try/Catch try using the below query.

```
   SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```

It will give you some more information on what is triggering the catch block to execute

More info on this retrieving error information can be found here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql